# Using reg exp extractor value from a request in one throughput controller to a request in another throughput controller

Tags: jmeter

I have a test which does following

- I have a GET request in one throughput controller. For this request I am using regular expression extractor to get value for a request  attribute.
- I have second throughput controller which has another GET request. To run this request I need use value of regular expression extractor from a GET request in first throughput controller.

I am able to do this if I have both requests in one throughput controller. But the same is not working if I have 2 requests in 2 different throughput controllers.

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no limitation for passing values from request under one controller to request under the other, provided they are in the same thread group. However, depending on your Throughput Controller settings, the first GET request may not run always run at the same time as the second GET request from second throughput controller. In other words, both Throughput controllers are making their decisions independently, and do not always make the same decision on whether to run the sampler under them or not.

To resolve this, you need to either introduce a dependency, so that second GET only runs if first got executed, or have 2nd GET to have a default value in case it's not available from the 1st request.

Here's one way to introduce a dependency, as example (many other ways are possible as well):

```
Throughput Controller 1
    GET 1
If Controller <-- check if GET 1 was executed
    Throughput Controller 2 <-- runs only if GET 1 was executed
        GET 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution.